# criterions for polar set of Feller processes

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, stochastic-processes, potential-theory

Suppose $X_t$ is the solution to 
$$
d X_t=b(X_t)dt+dL_t,\quad X_0=x. 
$$
where $L$ is a rotational symmetric $\alpha-$stable process with $\alpha\in (0,1]$, $b$ is Lipchitz.

Assume $\Gamma\subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ and $\ dim(\Gamma)<d-1$. Is it possible to prove $\Gamma$ is a polar set, which means 
$$
{\bf P}_x(T_\Gamma<\infty)=0, \quad \forall x\in \mathbb{R}^d? 
$$
where $T_{\Gamma}:=\inf\{t>0: X_t\in\Gamma \}$.

Comment: What if $X_t = X_0 + b t$ for some $b \ne 0$? Then even single points are non-polar. (They are semipolar, though).

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments. I didn't explain my question clear before, so I reedit it in an easier way. Thanks again if you can give me any comment or reference.

Comment: I am aware of numerous papers dealing with $\alpha \in (1, 2]$ (by [Bogdan–Jakubowski](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00220-006-0178-y), [Kim–Song–Vondraček](https://doi.org/10.1214/11-AOP682), [Chen–Wang](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/proc/12909)). The case $\alpha \in (0, 1]$ that you are interested in seems to be more difficult, at least with this approach, and I do not know any results in this direction.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki: Maybe some literatures about general Markov process will talk about this topic, but I have not find any related results. Any way, thank you again for your help.